# What are the kind of unit tests or tests in general that needs to be done on the following smart contract?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, solidity-0.8.x, unittesting

https://gist.github.com/shobhitic/44f1d88c58b8c80d431e156654167d0d

I am super new to testing so I am not entirely sure how to frame this question but what are the tests that should be done on a smart contract like this?
Are there any certain specific parameters that needs to be focused on or any specific testing libraries that I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in this kind of contract you would try to mint a token, then make sure that the ID is correct, and make sure that the balance of the receiver has increased of 1.
Then you would test the `withdraw()` function.

Depending on the smart contract framework you've chosen, you may also verify that the test coverage is enough to ensure that the code is fully tested and that the contract behaves as expected.